# Sitecore 9.0 Update 1 in PaaS: Error in Experience Profile

Tags: solr, azure, paas, xconnect

I have deployed my **Sitecore 9.0.1 solution in Azure PaaS with Self Signed Certificate**.I can't add contacts in List Manager and when I view the Experience Profile, I always get **"An error has occurred."** My Solr is also not getting any data.

I have tried the following:

1. Disable all the Azure config in xconnect root
2. Enable all the Solr Index writer and even added the solr core in connection strings
3. Added AllowInvalidClientCertificates="true" in connectionstrings.config
4. Restarted and Rebuild the XConnectSearchIndexer.exe

The logs say this:

1. Certificate was not found
   [image: Certificate was not found]
2. Could not establish trust relationship
   [image]

Is there any other options to have my self signed certificate work other than getting SSL Certificate from a trusted vendor? It will be of great help, if anybody can suggest some thoughts/documentations on it. Thanks

Comment: @SitecoreClimber I did what is stated there. But still having those errors above and not getting any data in Solr.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to connect to XConnect from your local machine. Is that correct?

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate. If the original answer needs more detail, please work with @SitecoreClimber in the context of that question, instead of a new one. It just dillutes the overall value of the site.

Comment: @MarkCassidy yes. Both xconnect and sitecore are in Azure Web App. and also establishing connection between xconnect and solr.

Comment: Yep. Well sounds more like you need interactive debugging, not really appropriate for the format. Starting the xConnect search indexer from D:\Home however, suggests to me you're trying to connect locally to your Azure xconnect. Which is covered in the original question. Otherwise find us on Slack.

Comment: To solve the Certificate Not found, 
allowInvalidClientCertificates = true, 
install certificate in SSL settings of App Service and
thumbprint == thumbprints in the Connection String.

Could not established an SSL Settings Soln

Besides disabling Azure configs and Enabling Solr Configs, make sure that the following are in true

For IndexReader & IndexWriter, set the RequireHttps to true
For IndexerSettings, set the IndexPIISensitiveData and IndexAnonymousContactData to true

Then if all the settings are configured properly, run the XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr